# How can I show the column name in lower case?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Table structure:

```
SQL>DESCRIBE tipsdb;

 Name                       Null?               Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USERNAME                                           CHAR(20)

 MAC                                                CHAR(20)

 PASSWORD                                           CHAR(50)

SQL>
```

Complete table output:

```
SQL> select * from tipsdb;


USERNAME
------------------------------------------------------------

MAC

------------------------------------------------------------

PASSWORD
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

arun

aabbccddeeff

whopee
```

Current output:

```
SQL> select PASSWORD as user_password from tipsdb;

USER_PASSWORD

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
whopee
```

Expected output:

```
SQL> select PASSWORD as user_password from tipsdb;

user_password
----------------------
whopee
```

In the above query I want the `user_password` column to be displayed in lower case instead of upper case.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the SQL*Plus [`column` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm) to override the default heading:

```
SQL> column username heading "username"
SQL> column password heading "password"
SQL> select username, mac, password from tipsdb
```

You don't have to enclose the desired heading in double-quotes to specify the case to use, but I think it's a bit clearer that it's intentional; and you do need the quotes if your heading has multiple words.

There is much more about [formatting columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#i1081036) in the [SQL*Plus User Guide and Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/toc.htm).

If your query specifies an alias for the column name then you need to refer to that alias in the `column` command.

But you can also make the alias itself lower-case, by enclosing that in double quotes, making it [a quoted identifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129):

```
SQL> select PASSWORD as "user_password" from tipsdb;
```

And because it's quoted you could use a space instead of an underscore it you wanted to:

```
SQL> select PASSWORD as "user password" from tipsdb;
```

You then don't need a `column` heading setting. Referring to a quoted identifier is generally a pain as they have to quoted and have exactly the same everywhere, but purely for display like this is can be useful.