# How to convert view column name from upper case to camel case?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a view and its column names are in upper case, so how can i convert column name from upper case to camel case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show the column name in lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500782/how-can-i-show-the-column-name-in-lower-case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use initcap function. e.g.

```
select initcap('your text here') from dual;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure this is going to change column names of table to Camel case ?

Comment: place your column name and table name

Answer (score 0):

use `initcap`

```
select initcap(columnname) from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT INITCAP( string1 ) from dual;
```

INITCAP( string1 ) may give you desired result.

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/initcap.php